# how to calculate MD5 hash and HMAC-SHA1 in c

Tags: c, ubuntu, hmacsha1, stun, gnutls

I have to prepare **Message Integrity Attribute** for TURN allocation request.

say my username is **user_1**, realm is **192.168.1.101** and password is **user_pass_1**

```
key = MD5(user_1:192.168.1.101:user_pass_1)
```

then I have to perform HMAC-SHA1 on a buffer using above key.

I want to use gnutls library for calculating HMAC-SHA1, is there any way to do it

Comment: Try Googling "hmac_sha1.c"

Comment: You can use OpenSSL's `HMAC_xxx` functions to do this